# How should I store user credentials so that users don't have to login again?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop

I have 2 activities: `Login` and `Main`

I also have `App` class that runs before the Activities.

```
public class App extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml` makes `Login` Activity be the first activity to run.

Should I go to the `Login` activity, check the [**SharedPreferences**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) then determine if user has already logged in?

Or Should I make a blank Activity that does this check then launches the correct Activity, either `Login` or `Main`?

Or Maybe the check should be done in the `App` class and a change made to the Android Manifest.

*So that this doesn't become an opinion fest, any suggestion has to have a logical reason behind it and why it would be best*.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving credentials its up on you. Ofc its better to keep it in safe place and encoded ; )

There are many possible solutions:

1) Splashscreen
Theoretically we should not use splash screens :P 
But in this case it will be super easy ;)

```
Intent mIntentMain = ...
Intent mIntentLogin = ...
boolean mIsUserLogged = ...
startActvity(mIsUserLogged ? mIntentMain : mIntentLogin);
```

2) Main Activity
Start main activity, and before filling the screen with data, ws calls etc, just after the onCreate, check credentials ;) if its
ok -> start parsing data / filling stuff
else -> finish main activity, show toast, open login activity

3) Fragments
Activity Main -> check credentials -> put login fragment or main fragment

Answer (score 1):

Good solution is create new class for holding information about session, e.g.:

```
public class SessionManager {
// Shared Preferences
SharedPreferences pref;

// Editor
Editor editor;

// Context
Context mContext;

// Shared pref mode
int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

// Sharedpref file name
private static final String PREF_NAME = "MyPref";

// All Shared Preferences Keys
private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";

// Constructor
public SessionManager(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = pref.edit();
}

/**
 * Create login session
 */
public void createLoginSession(String email, int id) {
    // Storing login value as TRUE
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);

    // Storing email in pref
    editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, email);

    // Storing id in pref
    editor.putInt(KEY_ID, id);

    // commit changes
    editor.commit();
}

/**
 * Check login method wil check user login status
 * If false it will redirect user to login page
 * Else won't do anything
 */
public void checkLogin() {
    // Check login status
    if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
        // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(mContext, LoginActivity.class);

        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        mContext.startActivity(i);
    }

}


/**
 * Quick check for login
 * *
 */
// Get Login State
public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
}

public int getId() {
    return pref.getInt(KEY_ID, 0);
}
}
```

And in your MainActivity you have to check if user is logged in or not:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Session Manager Class
SessionManager session;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    // Session class instance
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
    session.checkLogin();
.
 // code goes here
 ...
```

If user is not logged in he will be redirected to LoginActivity.

In LoginActivity just check email/pass or whatever,... call:

```
session.createLoginSession(mEmail, mId);
```

and redirect user back to MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

Check for login in `SharedPreferences` takes a little time and if you implement this check via blank activity the launch time of your app will be increased without a reason (time for launch 2 activities instead of 1 activity)

you can do check in your `MainActivity` and if it fails then run `LoginActivity`

Answer (score 0):

How are you handling signups? The whole login/signup/authentication flow, while seemingly easy on paper, can get pretty complex with lots of edge cases when you take into account multiple simultaneous logins, password changes, forgotten passwords, account deletions etc. That said, Android provides [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) designed specifically for this purpose and [this](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/) is one of the better tutorials on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can view splash screen while loading the application and in that time to check the user name and password.
Or you can upload the main screen with charging indicator to the user knew something was going on and the application not stuck.

Answer (score 0):

First approach:

I would suggest you to go with Fragments.

Launch `MainActivity` , check inside `onCreate()` whether the user's login session is valid, if it is valid go with your normal workflow, otherwise launch your `LoginFragment`

Second approach:

Go with a `SplashActivity` , check your login user session validity and decide the workflow

Third approach

Assume that user is logged in, and launch your `MainActivity` inside `onCreate()` check your users session validity , if invalid then launch `LoginActivity` and `finish()` your `MainActivity`

Undoubtly First one can be your best choice , but I should leave this decision to you. :)